# Wix | Why can't store autoload input text value into database

Tags: velo

I got a project at Wix web development.

My input text coded auto increment value, it successful showing the value, but when I want to submit the value to database, it can't store into it.

Tested few solution, but is not a best choice for long run.

My solution is after the loaded value I need copy paste the value into the same inputtext, then the value can successful store into database.

Feel like I need to retype the value or copy paste the value then only can store the value.

May I know what is the problem?